# How to load this JSON into List Object in C#?

Tags: c#, json

I have this JSON output from a web service.

```
{
  "address": "173.194.67.1",
  "country": "US",
  "stateprov": "California",
  "city": "Mountain View"
}
```

How Do I load it into a List typed as below using Newton Soft JSON library?

```
public class Item
    {
        public string address;
        public string country;
        public string stateprov;
        public string city;
    }
```

List items;

I am new to JSON.

thanks.

Comment: gotta take the json string, and deserialize it as a new `Item` instance

Answer (score 3):

Your json is not an array just a single object

```
var item =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(yourjsonstring);
```

Comment: Thanks L.B. !! Works.